# Azure Data Factory Event Based Trigger File to Execute the two different environment ADF pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to take your advise and approach, how to we implement if we have two different ADF with different subscription or environment, we decided to implement to use trigger file approach to identify the first ADF-A environment pipeline has been completed, so that we would have to automatically start/trigger the ADF-B environment pipeline. this is our goal to implement the solution for our project. kindly someone, please provide the best practice approach and component to implement above that solution.

I would be really appreciating your help for me to lean further on this platform.

Advance Thanks

Comment: Please do not use the tag [azure-pipelines] for questions related to Azure Data Factory pipelines. [azure-pipelines] is for questions related to Microsoft's Azure DevOps pipelines feature.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to trigger a `PipelineA` when a new file arrives using Event Triggers and then once the `PipelineA` run is completed successfully then initiate a `PipelineB` run then you can utilize the REST API using a web activity and initiate a pipeline run.

**Approach 1**:
To do this in in your `PipelineA` at the end of all activity have a web activity  to make a call to your `pipelineB` using the REST API - [Pipelines - Create Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run?tabs=HTTP).

Here is an article by a community volunteer on how to use REST API to trigger a pipeline run - [Execute Azure ADF Pipeline using REST API](https://medium.com/@rajbca00/execute-azure-adf-pipeline-using-rest-api-76d6cee5c473)

**Approach 2**:
The second approach could be, before end of your `PipelineA` write a dummy file to a blob location and create an event trigger for your `pipelineB` so that the event trigger looks for file creation in the same location where `pipelineA` writes a file before completion and as soon as it is created then the second `pipelineB` starts executing.